# Cannot choose SlidingMenu Library project to link to

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock, adt, slidingmenu

I am trying to deploy the same Android development environment on PC as the one I already have on my Mac.

In the Android application, I am using the `ActionBarsherlock` (http://actionbarsherlock.com/) lib and the `SlidingMenu` (https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) lib. According to what I did before, I downloaded and import both projects to the eclipse workspace.

I aligned the `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to be the same as my application, and link ActionBarSherlock to the SlidingMenu project, then trying to link the sliding menu project to my app.

I got this screen when I try to link the SlidingMenu project to my project:

[image]

As you can see, there's no option to choose the "library" (which is the slidingmenu project). I never saw this before. Please help me to figure out how to link the sliding menu lib to my project.

--- Update ---

Here's the screenshot of the SlidingMenu project Properties -> android Menu:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: have you checked that the SlidingMenu is a library in the Properties >> Android menu?

Comment: Hi @panini updated the screenshot of the SlidngMenu's project > Android menu

Comment: I've added an answer for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that the `SlidingMenu` library is declared as a library. Do one of the two following steps to ensure that.

1. Check this line in `project.properties` file, if missing, add it :

   android.library=true
2. Right click on `SlidingMenu` library >> Project properties >> Android (left menu) >> check the `Is library` field, under the SDK API Levels list.

Answer (score 1):

Re your updated screenshot, you need to select the `Is Library` option, or else the system won't recognize it as a library.